# Interrupt heavy processing

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm facing an issue with rxjs.
Basically, I have a method that makes an http request (using Angular's `HttpClientModule`), do some time-consuming parsing, sorting, etc... then store the result in a BehaviorSubject.

My problem is that the request does not take very long to complete, but the parsing does (simple methods).
I can have some other calls to same method which need to interrupt (discard) the previous processing.
All this needs to be able to be cleared via a boolean.

---

Some representations of the process:
*Interrupt*

```
A   >-request--processing----|
A'  >--------------request--processing----|
A'' >-----------------------request--processing----|
```

- `A` is interrupted by `A'` and never completes
- `A'` is interrupted by `A''` and never completes
- `A''` completes

*Clear*

```
A      >-request--processing----|
A'     >--------------request--processing----|
switch >----------------------stop----|
```

- `A` is interrupted by `A'` and never completes
- `A'` is interrupted by `switch` and never completes
- `switch` blocks any new request as long as it is `false`

---

So far, I'm unable to find a way to interrupt the processing when some new request is needed or a decent way to block new requests.
I was thinking maybe making my parsing method return an observable and mergeMapping it...

Any idea is welcome.

Comment: When you say that the parsing is taking a long time, just to clarify: the parsing is synchronous and happening on client side? If so as JS is single threaded you won't be able to do much unless you start using web workers

Comment: Yes everything is client side (No access to backend, unfortunately). I think I managed to pin-point my bottleneck though. I'll try something soon. Regarding web workers, I have given that a thought but it's a pain with angular...

Comment: A colleague built https://github.com/cloudnc/observable-webworker which is really good. I've also used that library to build a brute force mechanism for an Enigma machine and wrote about it here: https://dev.to/maxime1992/brute-forcing-an-encrypted-message-from-enigma-using-the-web-worker-api-166b it lets you completely abstract the web worker through streams so it'd actually be really easy to use in your use case I believe :)

Comment: I'll check that. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can set you observable to a [Subscription](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subscription) variable.

**Usage example:**

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/internal/Subscription';

/...

public subscription: Subscription;

onInit() {
    this.getData();
}

getData() {
    this.subscription = this.myService.getA().subscribe(...)
}

cancelService() {
   this.subscription.unsubscribe(); // This will cancel the request
}
```